# What function renders GLFW Window in OpenGL onto the screen?

Tags: c++, opengl, window, glfw

if I understand this correctly, `glfwCreateWindow` creates a window but doesn't actually render it on the screen. Which function in GLFW actually renders the window onto the screen?

(Many people think I am talking about rendering onto the window but what I mean is rendering the window onto the screen, not rendering objects onto the window)

Comment: `glfwShowWindow(PTR_TO_WINDOW)` shows the window, if it is previously set to "invisible" (by adding a call: `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE)` before `glfwCreateWindow`); otherwise the window will show automatically.

Comment: OpenGL renders into a framebuffer. The framebuffer is swapped with [`glfwSwapBuffers`](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.0/group__context.html#ga15a5a1ee5b3c2ca6b15ca209a12efd14)